# Steam login in .net 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I'm doing login via steam to my website (in C# .NET 7) but the login works strangely.. I'm calling login url which redirect me to my website on callback endpoint and there I veryfying login (another api call to steam) and sometimes I get success login and sometimes not success.. What could I do wrong?

**For login I'm calling url:**

[https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=[MY_RETURN_URL]&openid.mode=checkid_setup](https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=%5BMY_RETURN_URL%5D&openid.mode=checkid_setup)

**And for verifying login I'm calling url:**

https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login - in this url I add all query parameters which was returned in 1st api call and change *`openid.mode`* to *`check_authentication`*

-**so my final verify url looks like this:**

https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.mode=check_authentication&openid.op_endpoint=https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login&openid.claimed_id=https://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561198143838088&openid.identity=https://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/76561198143838088&openid.return_to=https://localhost:7195/steam/login/callback&openid.response_nonce=2023-07-05T07:32:55Z7xf9ZFE9SEUddG9kWkJ3aW28tqg=&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed,op_endpoint,claimed_id,identity,return_to,response_nonce,assoc_handle&openid.sig=GTb4rBrP6jqQjFNpk4Z1pktBa1I=

The urls I was doing by this issue:
[Steam OpenID Signature Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573820/steam-openid-signature-validation), but as I mentioned, it works rly strangely (sometimes yes, sometimes not)

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so problem was in http request method.. I was sending it as HttpGet but it has to be send as HttpPost. So I fix it like this:

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var param in _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Query)
{
    payload.Add(param.Key, (param.Key == "openid.mode" ? "check_authentication" : param.Value));
}

using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login")
{
    Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(payload!)
};

using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return false;
}

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    for (var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync(cancellationToken); line != null; line = await reader.ReadLineAsync(cancellationToken))
    {
        var parameter = line.Split(':');
        if (parameter.Length != 2)
            continue;
            
        parameters.Add(parameter[0], parameter[1]);
    }
}


return string.Equals(parameters["is_valid"], "true");
```