# Steam login issue using openId 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, openid, steam

[Steam OpenID Signature Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53573820/steam-openid-signature-validation)

We are trying to implement the steam login in the spring boot project through this link.
But we're in trouble, and we're going to use this method to get to the WebClient or RestTemplet
http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0 When validating data obtained from Steam with this link, the is_valid value is often output as false.
When I looked up the information to solve this login-related problem, I found the information saying, "Migration to openIdConnect and process it."
But I think the current error I've experienced is a problem that I can't verify when I send data normally in openid 2.0, but am I wrong?

The parameters that occur when you log in normally on the Steam side are as follows.

openidparams: eyJvcGVuaWQubnMiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9zcGVjcy5vcGVuaWQubmV0XC9hdXRoXC8yLjAiLCJvcGVuaWQuY2xhaW1lZF9pZCI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3NwZWNzLm9wZW5pZC5uZXRcL2F1dGhcLzIuMFwvaWRlbnRpZmllcl9zZWxlY3QiLCJvcGVuaWQuaWRlbnRpdHkiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9zcGVjcy5vcGVuaWQubmV0XC9hdXRoXC8yLjBcL2lkZW50aWZpZXJfc2VsZWN0Iiwib3BlbmlkLnJldHVybl90byI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo4MDgwXC9sb2dpblwvY2hlY2siLCJvcGVuaWQucmVhbG0iOiJodHRwOlwvXC9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MCIsIm9wZW5pZC5tb2RlIjoiY2hlY2tpZF9zZXR1cCJ9

decoding :

```
{
  "openid.ns": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0",
  "openid.claimed_id": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
  "openid.identity": "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
  "openid.return_to": "http://localhost:8080/login/check",
  "openid.realm": "http://localhost:8080",
  "openid.mode": "checkid_setup"
}
```

```html
<form action="https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="openid.identity" value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select">
                    <input type="hidden" name="openid.claimed_id" value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select">
                    <input type="hidden" name="openid.ns" value="http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0">
                    <input type="hidden" name="openid.mode" value="checkid_setup">
                    <input type="hidden" name="openid.realm" value="https://localhost">
                    <input type="hidden" name="openid.return_to" value="https://localhost/login/check">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-steam" id="js-sign-in">Sign in through <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="octicon octicon-steam" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M8 0a8 8 0 00-8 7.47c.07.1.13.21.18.32l4.15 1.67a2.2 2.2 0 011.31-.36l1.97-2.8v-.04c0-1.65 1.37-3 3.05-3a3.03 3.03 0 013.05 3 3.03 3.03 0 01-3.12 3l-2.81 1.97c0 .3-.05.6-.17.9a2.25 2.25 0 01-4.23-.37L.4 10.56A8.01 8.01 0 108 0zm2.66 4.27c-1.12 0-2.03.9-2.03 2s.91 1.99 2.03 1.99c1.12 0 2.03-.9 2.03-2s-.9-2-2.03-2zm0 .5c.85 0 1.53.66 1.53 1.49s-.68 1.5-1.53 1.5c-.84 0-1.52-.67-1.52-1.5s.68-1.5 1.52-1.5zM5.57 9.6c-.22 0-.43.04-.62.11l1.02.42c.65.26.95.99.68 1.62-.27.63-1 .93-1.65.67l-1-.4a1.73 1.73 0 003.13-.08c.18-.42.18-.88.01-1.3A1.69 1.69 0 005.57 9.6z" /></svg> Steam</button>
                </form>
```

```java
@Controller
public class SteamLoginController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @GetMapping("/login/check")
    public String check(
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.ns") String openidNs,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.mode") String openidMode,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.op_endpoint") String openidOpEndpoint,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.claimed_id") String openidClaimedId,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.identity") String openidIdentity,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.return_to") String openidReturnTo,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.response_nonce") String openidResponseNonce,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.assoc_handle") String openidAssocHandle,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.signed") String openidSigned,
            @RequestParam(value = "openid.sig") String openidSig,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) {
//        String body = WebClient.create("https://steamcommunity.com")
//                .get()
//                .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
//                        .path("/openid/login")
//                        .queryParam("openid.ns", openidNs)
//                        .queryParam("openid.mode", "check_authentication")
//                        .queryParam("openid.op_endpoint", openidOpEndpoint)
//                        .queryParam("openid.claimed_id", openidClaimedId)
//                        .queryParam("openid.identity", openidIdentity)
//                        .queryParam("openid.return_to", openidReturnTo)
//                        .queryParam("openid.response_nonce", openidResponseNonce)
//                        .queryParam("openid.assoc_handle", openidAssocHandle)
//                        .queryParam("openid.signed", openidSigned)
//                        .queryParam("openid.sig", openidSig)
//                        .build()
//                )
//                .retrieve()
//                .bodyToMono(String.class)
//                .block();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("User-Agent", "Your User Agent"); // Set your user agent

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login?" +
                        "openid.ns={ns}" +
                        "&openid.mode=check_authentication" +
                        "&openid.op_endpoint={opEndpoint}" +
                        "&openid.claimed_id={claimedId}" +
                        "&openid.identity={identity}" +
                        "&openid.return_to={returnTo}" +
                        "&openid.response_nonce={responseNonce}" +
                        "&openid.assoc_handle={assocHandle}" +
                        "&openid.signed={signed}" +
                        "&openid.sig={sig}",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                entity,
                String.class,
                openidNs, openidOpEndpoint, openidClaimedId,
                openidIdentity, openidReturnTo, openidResponseNonce,
                openidAssocHandle, openidSigned, openidSig
        );

        String body = responseEntity.getBody();
        boolean isTrue = Objects.requireNonNull(body).contains("true");
        System.out.println(isTrue);
        System.out.println(body);



        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(openidIdentity);
        String username;
        if (matcher.find()) {
            username = matcher.group();
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        SecurityUser user = SecurityUser.builder()
                .username("steam_" + username)
                .build();

        Authentication authentication =
                new OAuth2AuthenticationToken(user, user.getAuthorities(), "steam");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        
        session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
        
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", session.getId());
        cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);
        return "redirect:/check";
    }
```

output value:
false
ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0
is_valid:false